# Flutter Reduce padding between DataRows in DataTable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How i want it to look like (before -> after) :

[image]

Is it possible to do it like in this image?

edit: Solved it like Hugo said, by copying the code of data_table.dart into a new file, changing the _dataRowHeight, and using that instead.

Comment: Could you show the code that you're using for the before?

Comment: I would add the code if i could, but if i edit my post and add the code, it says "it looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details".

Comment: Without seeing how you're producing the before I don't see how it's possible to make any suggestions for the after. It's most definitely possible.

Comment: here: i screenshotted the code instead lol
https://gyazo.com/788754544ee0cf7292e1a39fd5ba9e3f
https://gyazo.com/c4a842113643f4ee6e59c4ae372a2b47

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do that in a simple way.

`_dataRowHeight` is an attribute (private, as you can see) defined inside `DataTable`. Since `DataRow` is not a `Widget`, you cannot force it to fit in a `Container`, as well.

The best option you got is copying the source code of `DataTable` in order to create your own `DataTable`, so you can modify the property `_dataRowHeight`.

Extending `DataTable` is also an option, but you would have to override the method `build()` and still copy a lot of content from `DataTable`.

Answer (score 5):

In Dart VM version: 2.7.0 this problem is solved. You can use parameter dataRowHeight to solve your problem. And there are more useful parameters:

```
DataTable({
Key key,
@required this.columns,
this.sortColumnIndex,
this.sortAscending = true,
this.onSelectAll,
this.dataRowHeight = kMinInteractiveDimension,
this.headingRowHeight = 56.0,
this.horizontalMargin = 24.0,
this.columnSpacing = 56.0,
this.showCheckboxColumn = true,
@required this.rows,  })
```

Answer (score 2):

After quickly glancing at the DataTable code it looks like padding is a private constant used for some private build methods within that class.

```
static const double _tablePadding = 24.0;
```

If you really need to use the DataTable widget then you could create your own class that extends DataTable and then override its build function to create your own _buildDataCell function where you could supply your own dimensions.

Comment: This may be a good feature request for the flutter team though. I feel like formatting data tables should be allowed. Not sure why all of the formatting is trapped in private constants.